# Will unsuccessful logon attempts to a RDP server be represented in the firewall logs?

Tags: logging, rdp

Assume the topology below:
[image]

Host A is remotely connecting with RDP to Host B, there is a firewall between them. Firewall's logs are collected and monitored.

When the user is prompted with a Windows Security pop up to enter a password and submits an incorrect one, what happens?

[image]

At the point the user at Host A is presented with a Windows Security pop up, has she already established a RDP session with Host B or is the session established after submitting a correct password? Or, my actual question is - what `action` will be seen in the firewall logs - `allowed` or `denied`?

I am asking this after I noticed 40 `allowed` firewall events in 7 minutes with destination port `3389`, from the same source to the same destination, and I don't know how to interpret what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall logs the traffic. It allows the traffic based on the rule configuration. The firewall log should show "allowed" because that is the disposition of that specific traffic. You allow inbound RDP, so the firewall logs this traffic as allowed.

The firewall log has nothing to do with the authentication failure and won't log the authentication failure. It logs the traffic.

Comment: So as I understand - one can't say from FW logs if the user did actually connect to Host B or not, just that traffic from Host A to host B is not blocked with firewall rules

Comment: Yes. Exactly...